# Dealing with lack of floating point precision in OpenCL particle system

Tags: floating-point, opencl, precision

I'm writing an OpenCL based particle system to speed up visualizations of large scale networks. In essence, this is a two phase problem where phase one applies negative gravity to each particle (typical n-bodies problem) so they all repel and phase two then attracts particles based on edges (or springs) between the particles.

During each iteration of the gravity algorithm each particle's location, represented as a pair of floats, is impacted by the distance to each other particle (classical physics model, no drag, keeping it simple).

In a situation where one has a perfectly spaced out square array of particles the application of gravity should result in symmetry across both the X and Y axes. This is true at the beginning of the gravity application, but over time the lack of precision inherent in adding together lots of floating point numbers results in small non-uniform deviations. This, in turn propagates through the entire n-body system and a loss of symmetry occurs.

One simple way to avoid this is to use double precision numbers, however the GeForce 9600M GT on my MacBook Pro does not support double precision numbers. So, what's a nice way to deal with such problems in OpenCL? I've thought about truncating the floating point numbers I'm adding to a few decimals to avoid this problem, but that seems like a bit hokey.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a pretty common problem; even on CPUs, sometimes you want to avoid the use of double precisions to avoid the factor of two in memory overhead/bandwidth.

A number of molecular dynamics and n-body codes written for GPUs use "mixed-precision" arithmetic; they store the particle positions and velocities as single precisions, but then they use double precision for a few key operations -- typically to store the position differences, and to accumulate the accelerations.   (googling ["mixed precision" "molecular dynamics"](http://www.google.ca/search?q=%22mixed%20precision%22%20%22molecular%20dynamics%22) or ["n-body"](http://www.google.ca/search?q=%22mixed%20precision%22%20%22n-body%22) gives tonnes of results).

So that reduces the number of double precision calculations, but not to zero.  To implement higher precision arithmetic than your hardware natively supports, you can do software emulation, emulating a double with two floats. There was a venerable fortran library [dsfun90](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/) which implemented this, and someone in [this NVidia forum](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=73067) implemented something similar in CUDA (based on the operations in NVIDIA's Mandelbrot example).  I don't know of an OpenCL implementation offhand but copying it over from CUDA should be pretty straightforward.  Obviously it's not as fast as native doubles, but if it's only for a few key operations it's not so bad.

Comment: Agreed, mixed precision approaches are definitely the way to go

Comment: Ding ding ding! "mixed precision" was the technical term I was looking for. I've started to implement a mixed precision model, taking a first stab at it by emulating a double for force aggregation. It's a whole lot slower and reminds me of the days of my 486sx. Optimization of my methods will help out a lot. However, I think it's probably a better time/value trade off to get a GPU with native double support and used mixed precision for force aggregation. Great answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

You've hit on most of the questions that are fundamental to the field of numerical analysis; you should prepare to do some reading on how these problems are typically dealt with.

First, if your problem has symmetry, you can exploit this to reduce the amount of computation needed, and also get rid of any spontaneous symmetry-breaking due to numerical error.

Second, realize that even when dealing with the same finite precision, not all algorithms are equal: some algorithms are more [numerically stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability) than others. Using higher-precision arithmetic doesn't eliminate numerical instability, it just makes it take longer to become apparent. It's likely that your gravity simulation currently implements what is equivalent to [Euler's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method). Without switching to double precision, you can make your simulation much more stable/accurate by using a higher-order method, such as [Runge-Kutta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods).

Lastly, it sounds like you're doing [force-directed graph layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-based_algorithms_%28graph_drawing%29). Simply running the physical simulation forward is prone to finding only a local optimum, highly dependent on the starting positions, and is (as you've discovered) usually quite unstable. The linked wiki page mentions several other methods that can do a much better job of solving the problem.

Comment: Excellent answer. You're right that I was using just a slightly modified version of Euler's method at this time. Implementing a Runge-Kutta force integrator greatly improved the model -- I'll port that to the CPU model too. However, even application of Runge-Kutta results in numeric imprecision, it just takes longer, as would be the case with switching to doubles.